# Angular 2 for TypeScript app testing - specs appear multiple times in jasmine

Tags: typescript, jasmine, angular, systemjs

I have followed this tutorial for testing an Angular 2 app: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html

After finishing with the `First app test` section and went to `unit-tests.html` I saw my spec reports appearing multiple times:

[image: jasmine unit-tests.html]

Although I haven't made any changes to the tutorial code, for a quick reference here is my unit-tests.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>Ng App Unit Tests</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css">

    <script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- #1. add the system.js library -->
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

<script>
    // #2. Configure systemjs to use the .js extension
    //     for imports from the app folder
    System.config({
        packages: {
            'app': {defaultExtension: 'js'}
        }
    });

    // #3. Import the spec file explicitly
    System.import('app/hero.spec')

    // #4. wait for all imports to load ...
    //     then re-execute `window.onload` which
    //     triggers the Jasmine test-runner start
    //     or explain what went wrong.
            .then(window.onload)
            .catch(console.error.bind(console));
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

hero.spec.ts

```
import {Hero} from './hero';

describe('Hero', () => {
    it('has name', () => {
        let hero:Hero = {id: 1, name: 'Super Cat'};
        expect(hero.name).toEqual('Super Cat');
    });
    it('has id', () => {
        let hero:Hero = {id: 1, name: 'Super Cat'};
        expect(hero.id).toEqual(1);
    });
});
```

Any idea what might went wrong?

Comment: This problem still persists when for the tutorial for Angular2.0.0-rc.5, i.e. the results for the simple tests for hero.ts are tripled. Note, tho, that the next set of tests in the tutorial, i.e. for the my-uppercase.pipe.ts, does not have tripled results. So it's not simply that all results are tripled, just some. I'm guessing it has something to do with finicky timing of things, e.g. the timing of when simple tests finish versus when more complicated tests that require something else (other downloads?) finish relative to, say, when the browser window finishes loading and jasmine re-starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As my previous comment is mark as deleted, I write down my final solution to evict the problem. This solution works and the only problem is that the first time it shows the HTML page with the text "No specs found" but when all modules are loaded, it shows all specs ans its results.

This solution is taken by the book "Angular 2 Development with TypeScript v7 MEAP" of Manning Early Access Program:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>Unit Tests</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css">
    <!-- #1. Polyfills -->
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <!-- #2. Zone.js dependencies -->
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js"></script>
    <!-- #3. Add specs dependencies -->
    <script src="app/treeNode.spec.ts"></script>
    <script src="app/template.spec.ts"></script>
    <script src="app/services/tree.side.service.spec.ts"></script>
    <script src="app/services/tree.service.spec.ts"></script>
    <!-- #4. Add Jasmine dependencies -->
    <script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/jasmine-expect/dist/jasmine-matchers.js"></script>
    <!-- #5. Add the system.js library -->
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script>System.packageWithIndex = true;</script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>

    <script>
        // #6. Configure SystemJS to use the .js extension for imports from the app folder
        System.config({
            packages: {
                'app': {defaultExtension: 'js'}
            }
        });

        var SPEC_MODULES = [
            'app/treeNode.spec',
            'app/template.spec',
            'app/services/tree.side.service.spec',
            'app/services/tree.service.spec'
        ];

        /**
         * #7. Import the spec files explicitly
         */
        Promise.all([
            System.import('@angular/core/testing'),
            System.import('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing')
        ])
        .then(function (modules) {
            var testing = modules[0];
            var testingBrowser = modules[1];
            testing.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(testingBrowser.BrowserDynamicTestingModule, testingBrowser.platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
            return Promise.all(SPEC_MODULES.map(function (module) {
                return System.import(module);
            }));
        })
        .then(window.onload)
        .catch(console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope you find this solution useful.

Comment: I think this should be the correct/accepted solution. I've been following the official online Angular2 (version 2.0.0-rc.5) tutorial, and the `hero.ts` test results are tripled (as in the original question here) but not the `my-uppercase.pipe.ts` test results (not discussed in the question). I used this solution, replacing the `SPEC_MODULES` array with the tutorial's `...spec(.ts)` files. In contrast to some of the other posted answers, this solution (A) reduces the inappropriate result tripling to single results, but also (B) maintains the implementation and reporting of subsequent tests.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your problem. See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/viMSZD?p=preview.

The only difference I see is that I included SystemJS library files before the Jasmine ones:

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/boot.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just speculation, but I wonder whether the original problem is not reproduced here because dependencies are loaded from "afar" (i.e. `"https..."`). I do get the inappropriate result tripling after following the official online Angular2.0.0-rc.5 tutorial, but there, for example, jasmine.js is loaded locally, i.e. from `<script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>`. Thus this answer doesn't solve the problem but it does provide some tantalizing evidence for why the problem sometimes, but not always, happens, i.e. maybe something to do with relative load times.

Comment: I was following the tutorial as well and including SystemJS library files before the Jasmine ones actually did work for me (locally). But I agree this is probably just masking the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same issue (test case appears 3 times instead of 1 time).

In order to fix it, I removed the `.then(window.onload)` call on the `System.import('app/hero.spec')` Promise.

It seems as if the SystemJS module is able to load hero.spec.js before the browser raises the window load event. This would make the subsequent call to window.onload function obsolete.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for the specs loaded after the browser raises the window load event. One (ugly) workaround that I find is to retard the execution of the specs enclosing them in a setTimeout. See [here](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1003) for more details.

Comment: This does "fix" the problem, but not in an appropriate way. I've been following the Angular2 tutorials (now at version rc.5) and the test results are tripled as in the original question. However, that is true only for the Hero tests, i.e. some extremely simple tests that don't require Angular. The next set of tests in the tutorial, testing a pipe, are not tripled. Implementing this solution reduces the original triple results to an appropriate single result, but the subsequent test results are completely skipped. Thus, this solution isn't an appropriate full solution.

Comment: I agree, this should not be the accepted answer. In fact as noted by @AndrewWillems, it will actually cause other tests to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this odd behaviour if i use `lite-server`. If you follow the example on the angular2 site you will find that they're using `live-server`(note the "**v**" instead of "**t**"). With `live-server` jasmine renders my tests correctly. Maybe there are some issues with `browser-sync` magic being injected into the html?

Comment: I don't know what the status of the official online Angular2 tutorials was when you originally posted this answer on June 22, 2016, but the current tutorials, posted for use with Angular2 version rc.5 does not show "live-server" anywhere in the tutorials in a google search, whereas "lite-server" does show up in a similar search. Thus, I really don't think this is going down a correct path to a solution and may be giving misleading "correct" results by, e.g. (just guessing here), forcing the browser to load other "stuff", delaying the tests, which somehow makes them not repeat on window.onload.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem and after importing the core shim library the issue **disappeared**. Also make sure to import it as the very first script.

```
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
```